# AJAX request to other page not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Currently I am trying to add content to my page using AJAX. Since it is my first time using AJAX I am not really sure about what I am doing. I wrote a bit of code here:

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery("#nearby_customers_link").click(function(){
      jQuery.ajax({
         url: template_url + "/ajax/test.php",
         data: "nearby=" + jQuery(this).data("city"),
         success: function(data) {
            jQuery(".test").html(data).slideDown();
         }
      });
   });
});
```

index.php:

```
echo"<a href=\"#\" data-nearby=\"".$city['city']."\" id=\"customers_link\">Blablablablablablabla</a>";

echo"<div class=\"test\"></div>";
```

test.php:

```
$city = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE `key` = '".esc_sql($_GET['city'])."'", ARRAY_A);
$customers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `city` IN('".implode("','", array_map("esc_sql", unserialize($city[0]['nearby'])))."') ORDER BY `company_name` ASC", ARRAY_A);

if(!empty($customers))
{
   echo"<div id=\"nearby_customers\">";
   echo"<h3>Blablablablabla</h3>";

   foreach($customers as $customer)
   {
      echo city_customer($customer);
   }

   echo"</div>";
}

echo"</div>";
```

Now I get an error saying this:

Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in C:\wamp\www\ajax\test.php on line 7

How do I fix this error?

Also I am not really sure what the data field means or does and I can't find it anywhere on the internet. If someone could explain a bit that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a mistake in your code. in test.php you are using variable `$_GET['city']`, but in fact the variable is called `$_GET['nearby']`. Try fixing that and seeing if it works.

Comment: Changed it and now it works fine. Thank you kind sir.